# Iterando una clase, ¿cómo saber si un elemento es de una clase hija?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase *State*, que es el padre de la clase *CompositeState* (que es la misma clase, solo que contiene un arraylist de *States*). Si yo hago un `for(State s : states)` y quisiera comprobar si *s* es un *CompositeState* o un *State*, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?
He probado con `getClass().getName()` pero no me funciona, tambien he probado con comprobar si `s.getStates() == null` pero tampoco.

Comment: Buen dia te invitamos a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina,y ver como realizar una correcta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),considera agregar tu código para poder brindar una respuesta acertada

Comment: Buenas, creo que no me expresé bien, lo unico que necesito saber es, teniendo una clase B que hereda de A, en un bucle de elementos A p.e. for(A a : as) como comprobar if(a pertenece a clase B)

Comment: puedes usar intanceof,tambien if(objetoState.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("State"));

Comment: Gracias! Justo era eso, me has salvado jajaja, como puedo votar tu comentario? No me aparece ningún boton más que el de reportarlo :S

Comment: @Dramaturgo ponlo como respuesta :)

Comment: y para que querrias saber si un elemento es de una clase hija? El simple hecho de saberlo implica problemas de cohesion

Comment: Porque si era de una clase hija el método tenía que proceder de una forma y si era de la clase padre de otra

Comment: @Rober para eso igual quieres sobreescribir el método en la clase hija.

Answer (score 1):

Algunas formas de poder lograrlo

El operador instanceof devuelve verdadero o falso si un objeto pertenece o no a una clase determinada. Sintaxis:

`identificadorInstancia instanceof identificadorClase`

obteniendo el nombre de la clase del objeto

```
if(objeto.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("nombreDeLaClase"))
```

comparación directa de clases

```
if(objeto.getClass()==NombreDeClase.class)
```